# Grouping ORDER ITEMS from hourly to daily

Tags: sql, ssas

I would like to SUM the price of these Order Items together for each Order for a Contract.

I want to reduce my granularity from hourly to daily and so reduce the row count that we pass to the fact table and then the SSAS cube.

i.e. Contract A which can have many Orderlines, consider Orderline 1 which can have many Order Items.
I have had to screen the Order Items, but they are just sequential id numbers.

The problem is that I have to roll this up to a daily granularity from hourly, but still be able to give users on the cube access to the Order Item level

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SUM` as a window function. this will effectively write the same sum to multiple rows for each order-item; just like the `price`.

for example

```
SELECT ......
, SUM(price) OVER (PARTITION BY order_item)
....
FROM ....
GROUP BY ....
```

Comment: Doesn't give me what I am looking for.